# Receiving a Call Using Twilio Programmable Voice SDK

Tags: python, twilio, voip

I'm following the [Quickstart Guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started) using a python deployment on Heroku and am able to place calls just fine. It's the receiving that I'm having problems with. I've not modified any of the init or delegate logic for either the `TVOIncomingCall` instance or the `PKPushRegistry`.  And indeed, when I compile, the log says `"pushRegistry:didUpdatePushCredentials:forType"` and `"Successfully registered for VoIP push notifications."`  This makes me think my incoming handler on my server.py is the problem.

My question is this: **What's the proper way, in python, to fire off the VoIP push notification to notify the user of an incoming call?** I've enabled VoIP Services in my app and generated a VoIP services certificate (.p12) and received a valid `PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID` for my efforts, but what to do with it?

The Quickstart says to hit my server's 'placeCall' endpoint, so I update my Twilio number's incoming path and point it accordingly in the dashboard, but this results in "An Application Error has occurred" response whenever anyone calls my Twilio number.

Here is the relevant code from my server.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.jwt.access_token import AccessToken, VoiceGrant
from twilio.rest import Client
import twilio.twiml

ACCOUNT_SID = 'ACxxxxxxxx'
API_KEY = 'SKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
API_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID = 'CRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
APP_SID = 'APxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCOUNT_AUTH = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

IDENTITY = 'MyApp' #not literally

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/accessToken')
def token():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
  api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
  push_credential_sid = os.environ.get("PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID", PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID)
  app_sid = os.environ.get("APP_SID", APP_SID)

  grant = VoiceGrant(
    push_credential_sid = push_credential_sid,
    outgoing_application_sid = app_sid
  )

  token = AccessToken(account_sid, api_key, api_key_secret, IDENTITY)
  token.add_grant(grant)

  return str(token)


@app.route('/placeCall', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def placeCall():
    account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
    api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
    api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
    push_credential_sid = os.environ.get("PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID", PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID)
    app_sid = os.environ.get("APP_SID", APP_SID)

    CALLER_ID = request.values.get('From')
    IDENTITY = request.values.get('To')

    #client = Client(api_key, api_key_secret, account_sid)
    client = Client(api_key, api_key_secret, account_sid, app_sid, push_credential_sid)
    call = client.calls.create(to='client:' + IDENTITY, from_= 'client:' + CALLER_ID)
    return str(call.sid)
```

My `Identity` value is clearly wrong. I would think it would need to equal a reference to an app instance somehow. In the quickstart python example, `IDENTITY = 'voice_test'` Also, where does the `PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID` come into play?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE

______**

As per @philnash's comment, I've nested the `client` noun inside the `dial` verb. Here's my new `/incoming` endpoint:

```
@app.route('/incoming', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming():
    CALLER_ID = request.values.get('From')
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.dial(client = IDENTITY, callerId = CALLER_ID, record = "record-from-answer-dual")
    return str(resp)
```

This now results in a 'Schema validation warning' in the debugger stating 'unknown or unexpected nested elements' as a possible cause. Am I registering the client incorrectly? The old SDK allowed you to explicitly pass in your clientName as a parameter.

The `IDENTITY` string in my server.py is:

1. Defined outside of any method scope.
2. Used in the generation of an accessToken
3. Nested in the `client` noun of the `dial` verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `/placeCall` endpoint is not for your Twilio number's incoming call webhook. In the example it is used to simply generate a call to your client.

Instead, your incoming call webhook should point at an endpoint that will return some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) instructing Twilio to dial your client. TwiML is just a subset of XML and the elements you will need are [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with a nested [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client). Your endpoint should return something like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>YOUR_CLIENT_NAME</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

**Update**

Based on the update in the question, we now need to generate this TwiML in Python. You can [nest TwiML](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/twiml.html) with the [Twilio Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) using Python's `with` syntax. I believe this should work:

```
@app.route('/incoming', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming():
    CALLER_ID = request.values.get('From')
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    with resp.dial(callerId = CALLER_ID, record = "record-from-answer-dual") as dial:
        dial.client(IDENTITY)
    return str(resp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Phil! I've updated my original question. Please see comments in the Update section. :)

Comment: Thanks for updating. I don't think you're doing the nesting properly, check my updated answer.

Comment: OK! Now we're getting somewhere! Updated server with your suggestion and am now getting 'Error - 52134 - Invalid APNs device token'.  I will regenerate and upload a new VoIP Services Certificate and update my Push Credential SID. Thanks Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID` value in the application server's `server.py` file with your new push credential SID. It goes with the following constants at the top of the file:

```
ACCOUNT_SID = 'AC***'
API_KEY = 'SK***'
API_KEY_SECRET = '***'
PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID = 'CR***'
APP_SID = 'AP***'
```

And in your `placeCall` function:

```
def placeCall():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
  api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
  push_credential_sid = os.environ.get("PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID", PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID)
  app_sid = os.environ.get("APP_SID", APP_SID)
```

It seems like you're also missing the `APP_SID` from above which is the reference to [TwiML app](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started#create-a-twiml-application) that contains some call instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the response Megan! I should have shared more code from the start, but most of what you told was in fact already in my server.py. I hadn't included the the last two lines in the 'placeCall' function. However, it's there now, but calls placed to my Twilio number still result in the dreaded "Application Error has occured" response message.